# Code First EF6 not retrieving internal objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

apparent duplicate is for ef5, this is ef6, but the answer I needed was virtual (lazy loading) not present in the apparent duplicate

I think I have screwed up my code first approach...

initially we did code first from database, and everything was working well, however from up the chain a new requirements came in and so we scrapped that database, updated the code to match then generated a new database using code first.

we kept the old project in place, just changed everything we needed to and cleaned up the code removing all the auto generated stuff from the initial (code first from database) so we could do proper code first to database.

the problem here is that the class (i am simplifying to a two classes vs the entire code base) ImageCoordinates contains an Imagedata object but in code when I retrieve teh ImageCoordinates it returns null for the imageData object...

```
public class ImageCoordinate
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string coordinates { get; set; }

    public ImageData ImageData { get; set; }
}

public class ImageData
{
    [Key]
    public Guid uid { get; set; }

    [Column("imageData")]
    public byte[] imageData1 { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string fileName { get; set; }
}
```

the dbContext class contains

```
public class dbContext : DbContext
{
    public dbContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<ImageCoordinate> ImageCoordinates { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ImageData> ImageDatas { get; set; }
}
```

when retreiving...

```
var foo = dc.ImageCoordinates.FirstOrDefault(x => x.uid == uid);

foo.ImageData //is null
```

on the database side the auto generated structure....

```
 uid                                     coordinates    ImageData_uid
AC5712F6-B69B-44FE-A255-3F3227E02802    34,15,158,56    FFE0473D-4CF7-4B26-BE8A-A24FC79B6695
```

can anyone explain what I have done wrong here to prevent the system from generating that link and retreiving all data for the imageCoordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So either declare your associated property as `virtual` to enable lazy-loading, or use an `Include` to load the associated data at the point of materialization.

```
public virtual ImageData ImageData { get; set; }
```

or

```
dc.ImageCoordinates
  .Include(ic => ic.ImageData)
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.uid == uid);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want that you navigation properties are [lazy loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy) then you need to declare them as `virtual`:

```
public class ImageCoordinate
{
   //...
  public virtual ImageData ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) you will find a good explanation about the requirements that you must follow if you want to enable lazy loading for your entities and to have the Entity Framework track changes in your classes as the changes occur.

FYI, EF have three ways to load related entities: [lazy loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy), [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eager) and [explicit loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicit). The most used are the first two.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want is ***Lazy Loading***. It is enabled by default. It must get all child entites which have declared with `virtual` keyword. So consider to change this property to `virtual`.

```
public class ImageCoordinate
{
    ...
    public virtual ImageData ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can use `Include` which will load child entity which have declared in query. This process is known as **Eager Loading**.

```
dc.ImageCoordinates
  .Include(x=> x.ImageData)
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.uid == uid);
```

Also, you can enable Lazy Loading manually in context constructor:

```
public MyEntitiesContext() : base("MyEntitiesContext")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have my upvote, I don't like see good answers without upvotes. Of course I'm agree that spender's answer should be marked as the answer because he was the first in answer this question, but our answers respond the question too and they have their own contributions